# JSON-API How to Fetch Products Except Out of Stock?

Tags: json, json-api

## What I Want to Do

I want to specify a resource with a `where not exists other relationship` clause. Like below:

> GET /products?exclude=out_of_stock HTTP/1.1

Fetch all products, except the products out of stock (`out_of_stock` is a relationship!)

## Problem

I cannot find a documented solution for excluding resources based on (not) existence of other resources.

## Question

Is there a (documented) manner or best practice to specify this exclude in the url? I don't need code examples, but only the url specification.

Comment: Could you please add more details to your question?

Comment: Excuse me, I improved my question

Answer (score 1):

The following request looks fine to me:

```
GET /products?exclude=out_of_stock HTTP/1.1
```

However you could consider *inclusion* instead of *exclusion*:

```
GET /products?status=out_of_stock,in_stock HTTP/1.1
```

And define a default behavior for situations which the query parameter is not provided.

Comment: Thank you! In my case `out_of_stock` is another resource (type). There is a relationship between `product` and `out_of_stock`. But, if there's a relationship, I want to exclude: an inverted include.

Further, how to deal with filters in this case?  `/products?exclude=out_of_stock&filter[out_of_stock.date][lte]=1483228799`